# Typescript Promise not generic after Version update?

Tags: typescript, generics

Iam bit confused and could use some help before I deconstruct my whole app again.

I updated my Angular 4 App to Angular 5. And set the Typescript version to 2.4.2
Now my IDEA Editor says **"Type Promise is not generic"** on such lines e.g.:

```
putUserRegister(user: User): Promise<User>
  {...
```

Iam using es5 and it compiles (besides the outdated fullcalendar-another problem).

Do someone know where it comes from and/or how to get rid of it?

Thanks in advance!
Gregor

Answer (score 0):

Using promises can be dependent on your target JavaScript version.

You should be able to solve your problem by targeting a later version:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ESNext", // <-- Later ES version
      "module": "amd",
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": false,
      "preserveConstEnums": false,
      "removeComments": false
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "test",
      ".git"
    ]
}
```

Or by configuring your library includes. Example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES5", // <-- ES5
      "module": "amd",
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": false,
      "preserveConstEnums": false,
      "removeComments": false,
      "lib": [ // <-- lib config
        "es5",
        "es6",
        "dom",
        "es2015.core",
        "es2015.collection",
        "es2015.generator",
        "es2015.iterable",
        "es2015.promise",
        "es2015.proxy",
        "es2015.reflect",
        "es2015.symbol",
        "es2015.symbol.wellknown",
        "esnext.asynciterable"
      ]
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "test",
      ".git"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill try it out!